# C++ Syntax : ClassA : private vector<T> {} meaning

Tags: c++

I'm reading a C++ file. There is some structure I don't understand in C++, but I don't know how to google to learn this. Here is a piece of code that i'm reading :

```
template <typename value_type>
class iterstack: private vector<value_type> {
   private:
      using vector<value_type>::crbegin;
      using vector<value_type>::crend;
      using vector<value_type>::push_back;
      using vector<value_type>::pop_back;
      using vector<value_type>::back;
      typedef typename vector<value_type>::const_reverse_iterator
              const_iterator;
   public:
      using vector<value_type>::clear;
      using vector<value_type>::empty;
      using vector<value_type>::size;
      const_iterator begin() { return crbegin(); }
      const_iterator end() { return crend(); }
      void push (const value_type& value) { push_back (value); }
      void pop() { pop_back(); }
      const value_type& top() const { return back(); }
};
```

In above code, theresomething I don't understand.

Firstly :

```
class iterstack: private vector<value_type>
```

what is the difference above line with `class iterstack: vector<value_type>` (without `private` keyword)

Secondly :

```
using vector<value_type>::crbegin;
```

I'm really don't understand this line. `using` keyword, I often use under this form : `using namespace std` Another way of using makes me confusing.

Please tell me the meaning of two points above.

Thanks :)

Comment: One question per question, please. This is a database not a message board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `private` in `class iterstack: private vector<value_type>` means that `vector<value_type>` is a private base class. Base classes of a class are private by default so in this case the added private keyword has no effect. If a base class is private then its public and protected interface is added as private functions etc. to the derived class.

```
class Base {
    public:
    void fun(){}
};
class Derived1 : public Base { };  //fun() is public member function
class Derived2 : Base{}; //fun() is private
class Derived3 : private Base {}; //fun is private
class Derived4 : private Base {
    public:
    using Base::fun; //fun is public
}
```

With `using vector<value_type>::crbegin;` the public member function `crbegin` which is private in `iterstack` (because it is from a base class that is inherited with `private` keyword) is made `public`.

Comment: The base class' *non-private* members are accessible as private members of the derived type. This means *protected* are also accessible.

Comment: No, `crbegin` isn't made public; that using-declaration is private. (Just like your last example, which incorrectly says "fun is public"). `clear`, `empty` and `size` are made public.

Comment: thanks for the corrections juanchopanza and Mike Seymour, I must not be awake yet ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're simply inheriting `private`ly from the `vector`. In which the base class is a `vector` and derived class is an `iterstack`.

And next thing you're doing is making `crbegin` public in the `iterstack`.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference above line with `class iterstack: vector<value_type>` (without private keyword)

There's no difference. In a class defined using the `class` keyword (rather than `struct`), inheritance is private by default; so it is private whether or not you explicitly say so (as the code does) or leave the `private` keyword out.

> I'm really don't understand this line. `using` keyword

That's a *using declaration*, which makes a single name available in the current scope. It's used here to make names from the (private) base class available as members of this class.

> I often use under this form : `using namespace std`

That's a *using directive* which dumps the entire contents of a namespace into the current scope. If you often use `using namespace std` to dump the standard library into the global namespace, then that's a bad habit that you should get out of; it pollutes the namespace with many, many unwanted names, which could clash with names your program wants to use. Namespaces exist for a good reason - use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is about private inheritance. Inheriting with the `private` keyword, as in `class iterstack: private vector<value_type>`, essentially makes the fact that the class is inheriting from `vector<value_type>` known only to `iterstack`. That is, it inherits from `vector<value_type>`, and can use all of `vector<value_type>`'s functionality internally, but the rest of the program doesn't know that it inherits from `vector<value_type>` and so can't treat it as an object of type `vector<value_type>`, as it can in `class iterstack: public vector<value_type>`. You can find more info about private inheritance here: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

Your second question is about the usage of the `using` keyword in `using vector<value_type>::crbegin;`. The word `using` in this context has the effect of making `crbegin` from `vector<value_type>` a public member of the class. It's essentially doing the same thing as `using namespace std;`, except instead of introducing all of the names from the `std` namespace into the namespace of a function, it's introducing the specific name `crbegin` from `vector<value_type>` into the namespace of the class, which has the effect of making it a public member of the class. You can find more info about the many uses of the `using` declaration here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Answer (score 0):

the private keyword is declaring the superclass vector as private so that you cannot change the superclass.